# ILogger does not write to ApplicationInsight if use DependencyInjection in an Azure Function C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I use DI pattern for Azure Functions, so, I created startup file which looks like:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public sealed class Startup : FunctionsStartup
  {
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.Services.AddLogging();
      builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyManager, Mymanager>();
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

and the Azure Function:

```
public sealed class MyFunc
{

  public MyFunc(IMyManager manager)
  {
     _myManager = manager;
  }

  [FunctionName("MyFunc")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
  {
    log.LogInformation("this is a test"); // this log appear in Application Insights
    ...
  }
```

and MyManager:

```
public sealed class MyManager: IMyManager
{
   public MyManager(ILogger<MyManager> log)
   {
      _log = log;
   }
   
   public async Task ExecuteAsync(...) 
   {
      _log.LogInformation("Execute MyManager"); // this log does not appear in app insights
   }
}
```

Seems that ILogger or any injected logger, does not reflect in Application Insights. Should I define it in host.json file ?

I thought that should work in place without make changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) you must configure your host.json:

*"The host.json file configuration determines how much logging a functions app sends to Application Insights."*

You should at least [enable the critical level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) logging.

Comment: And if I want to log all information (I have managers with `_log.LogInformation` and where `_log` is `ILogger<T>`), should I use in `host.json` the following setting: `"Host.Results": "Information", "Function": "Information"` ? Or is enough `"default": "Information"` ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Yep, that's it :) Be ware, it's not host.config but host.json.

Comment: Yep for which question ? The first or second one :) ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Sorry, I wasn't clear. Both ways are ok, "default" will be set to all the loggers unless it's overriden by a specific policy like "Function" or "Host.Results".